# Add Resolve-DNSname to Hashtable

Tags: powershell, hashtable

Right now i have this hastable

```
Get-Content (path) |ForEach-Object {
  if($_ -match '\(((?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})\) disconnected. (\d+) message\[s\]'){
  
    $IP = $matches[1]
    $msgCount = $matches[2] -as [int]

    $SMTP[$IP] += $msgCount
   }
 }
```

my keys in that hashtable are IPv4 Adresses, for which i need a Resolve-DNSname and preferably the resolved DNS Name should be another Value for each key. Is it possible to do so and also show when an error occurs while Resolving the Dns name?

Example for the File

```
30.11.2020 05:05:39   SMTP Server: (Servername) (255.255.255.255) disconnected. 1 message[s] received
 30.11.2020 05:05:39   SMTP Server: (Servername) (255.255.254.254) disconnected. 2 message[s] received
 30.11.2020 05:05:39   SMTP Server: (Servername) (255.255.255.255) disconnected. 4 message[s] received
 30.11.2020 05:05:39   SMTP Server: (Servername) (255.255.234.245) disconnected. 4 message[s] received
 30.11.2020 05:05:40   SMTP Server: (Servername) (255.255.253.244) disconnected. 1 message[s] received
 30.11.2020 05:05:41   SMTP Server: (Servername) (255.255.255.255) disconnected. 46 message[s] received
 30.11.2020 05:05:41   SMTP Server: (Servername) (255.255.234.245) disconnected. 13 message[s] received
```

Comment: Please show us an example of the file you are parsing. The dot after `disconnected` should be escaped with a backslash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot add extra values to a Hashtable (it only has a Key and a Value), but you can do that if you use PSObjects which can have many properties.

```
$result = Get-Content -Path 'D:\Test\test.txt' | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_ -match '\(((?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})\) disconnected\.?\s+(\d+) message\[s\]'){
        try {
            $dns = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry($matches[1]).HostName
        }
        catch { 
            $dns = 'Not available' 
        }
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            IP       = $matches[1]
            Messages = [int]$matches[2]
            DNSName  = $dns
        }
    }
 }

#output on screen
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

# output to Csv file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\output.csv' -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation
```

If you want the 'Messages' counted together, you can group the results by the IP like this:

```
$cumulative = $result | Group-Object -Property IP | ForEach-Object {
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        IP       = $_.Name
        Messages = ($_.Group | Measure-Object -Property Messages -Sum).Sum
        DNSName  = $_.Group[0].DNSName
    }
}

#output on screen
$cumulative | Format-Table -AutoSize

# output to Csv file
$cumulative | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\cumulative_output.csv' -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation
```

---

To also include the (most recent) date, we need to adjust the regex:

```
$result = Get-Content -Path 'D:\Test\test.txt' | ForEach-Object {
    if($_ -match '^\s*(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).*\(((?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})\) disconnected\.?\s+(\d+) message\[s\]'){
        try {
            $dns = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry($matches[2]).HostName
        }
        catch { 
            $dns = 'Not available' 
        }
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            IP       = $matches[2]
            Messages = [int]$matches[3]
            DNSName  = $dns
            Date     = [datetime]::ParseExact($matches[1], 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss', $null)
        }
    }
 }

#output on screen
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

# output to Csv file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\output.csv' -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation
```

If you want the 'Messages' counted together, you can group the results by the IP like this:

```
$cumulative = $result | Group-Object -Property IP | ForEach-Object {
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        IP = $_.Name
        Messages = ($_.Group | Measure-Object -Property Messages -Sum).Sum
        DNSName = $_.Group[0].DNSName
        Date    = ($_.Group | Sort-Object Date)[-1].Date
    }
}

#output on screen
$cumulative | Format-Table -AutoSize

# output to Csv file
$cumulative | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\cumulative_output.csv' -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation
```

Output would be something like:

```
IP              Messages DNSName              Date              
--              -------- -------              ----              
255.255.255.255       51 Not available        30-11-2020 5:05:41
255.255.254.254        2 smtp.somecompany.com 30-11-2020 5:05:39
255.255.234.245       17 www.somecompany.com  30-11-2020 5:05:41
255.255.253.244        1 Not available        30-11-2020 5:05:40
```

Comment: Now the output looks like: 
ip          1 System.Net.IPHostEntry
ip          1 System.Net.IPHostEntry
ip          1 System.Net.IPHostEntry

so my incomming messages arent counted up anymore and the hostname isnt resolved

Comment: Change `[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry($matches[1])` to `[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry($matches[1]).HostName` and it should show you what you want @Trippin

Comment: @Trippin I have fixed that (forgot `.HostName`, thanks Mathias!) and added code to group the objects in $result in order to add up the number of messages per IP.

Comment: it displays it correctly now, but he is missing the ones where he couldnt get an Hostname

Comment: @Theo apparently he also doesnt display some of the ips in my first Hashtable, i aint sure why

Comment: @Trippin I have added new code to include the most recent date. You keep talking about a Hashtable, but what you show is a flat file with data to parse.. Using your example fie works for me.

Comment: @Theo could you change the regex to this, because i changed the example file a little bit and it wont fit with the date//  [12CC:0009-120C] 30.11.2020 05:05:39   SMTP Server: Server.Name.server.name (10.99.81.53) disconnected. 1 message[s] received

Comment: @Trippin Just remove the `^\s*` from the start of the regex. You didn't update the question with the new format though.. Remember that we cannot see your screen, so all we have is the information **you** provide. If that is not what the `real` file looks like, then code based on that won't work in real life..